# Self Referencing cell formula

Tags: excel

First post so pls be gentle!!

I'm trying to write a formula to work out what to charge people when I want to make a certain % margin.

Charge = Our cost (item, postage & fees)  / 1-margin as a % (dynamic)

The issue is the fees as that is based on the Charge,

In a simplified form, the formula (a1) is

=sum(B1+C1+(a1/d1)/0.7)

- What to charge - A1 (formula)
- Cost of Item - B1 = 20
- Cost of postage C1 = 40
- Fees d1 = 15%

is this even possible. I know that will obviously error as its a circular reference

TIA

EDIT: I'm just trying to write a formula to work out what to charge when I want to make x % again maybe it needs to be changed completely, (sorry) If my item cost is £3, my postage is £2, fees are 10% of the total charged and i want to make 30% - what do i need to charge

Edit 2: Thank you for those that helped and not just told me the maths was impossible. I managed to do it. I have added the image here incase anyone is interested in how i did it

Comment: That math is impossible. Show us some real numbers how they relate because that is not possible, no matter what language you write it in. (I'm assuming `a1` == `A1`)

Comment: Your fee statement is circular by nature.

Comment: I'm just trying to write a formula to work out what to charge when I want to make x %

again maybe it needs to be changed completely, (sorry) 

If my item cost is £3, my postage is £2, fees are 10% of the total and i want to make 30% - what do i need to charge

Comment: Alright that's more like it. `((3+2)+(3+2)*0.1)*1.3`. sounds more like this is a math issue than Excel issue

Comment: no, sorry the 10% isnt of the cost its of what i charge

Comment: You said `fees are 10% of the total`. (3+2)*0.1 is 10% fees on the total

Comment: My bad - the fees are of the total charged (also thanks for your help)

Comment: Then you are back in the circular referencing

Comment: yes but it is possible somehow as this calculator does it (maybe just not poss in excel??)

https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/selling-price-calculator.php

Comment: It's not Excel its basic **math** impossible.

Comment: @CalvynBlay-Field - If you read through that page, you should be able to easily set up in Excel. Set up that page as you want to do in Excel, and share the full link here (they give it to you in that text box at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-arrange your data:

[image]

Then, in `A4`, put: `=(A1+A2)*(1+A3)`.  This is the minimum of what you'd need to charge.

Then put the margin you want in `A6`, and in `A7` put: `=A4*(1+A6)`.  This is the minimum amount to charge, in order to make your desired margin.

Edit: Per your comment under the OP, you get `$7.15`

[image]

Comment: Thanks - my bad, by total i meant total charged rather than total cost

Comment: @CalvynBlay-Field - Does what I posted work for you?

Comment: yes - i used your advice and worked it out 

https://prnt.sc/pglkn8